# why my code is returning only one row from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

this the code which  I am working on and it is only returning one row from the database

```
    $positions =[];
        $rows= query("SELECT symbol,shares from portfolio where id=?",
        $_SESSION["id"]);
        foreach($rows as $row)

{

$stock =lookup($row["symbol"]);

if($stock!== false){
$positions =[
"symbol" =>$row["symbol"],
"nam" =>$stock["name"],

"shares" => $row["shares"],
"pric" =>$stock["price"],
"total" => $stock["price"] * $row["shares"]
];
}
}
render("portfolio.php",["ways" =>$positions,"title"=>"Portfolio"] );
```

lookup is function. below code is for portfolio.php

```
<?php foreach($ways as $position =>$values) : ?>

<th>
<?= $values ?>
</th>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

below is the query function declared in the above (top most) code.

```
 function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
    {
        // SQL statement
        $sql = func_get_arg(0);

        // parameters, if any
        $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

        // try to connect to database
        static $handle;
        if (!isset($handle))
        {
            try
            {
                // connect to database
                $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
                $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                // trigger (big, orange) error
                trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
                exit;
            }
        }

        // prepare SQL statement
        $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
        if ($statement === false)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }

        // execute SQL statement
        $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

        // return result set's rows, if any
        if ($results !== false)
        {
            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? You have a wrapper around the `Query` function which is intended to return an array. However, we don't know what's in that function so we can't really say. Show us `function query()`

Comment: query function has been added

Answer (score 2):

Because in your SQL you are defining a specific ID which usually can only be one

```
i.e.  where id=?
```

So if you need more results you have to expand your criteria

```
e.g. WHERE id > 5 AND id < 10
```

Comment: but the table contains multiple rows having same id

Comment: interesting choice of naming in the table you are working with then :), is it possible to dump the **$rows** value in? what will be the value if you don't include any criteria (e.g. "SELECT symbol,shares from portfolio")